# Xpages Frame navigate / X-Frame option

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, hcl

[image: **enter image description here**]

I have a xpages application running on Domino 9.0.0 which we had upgraded now on 10.0.1FP4, the application is loaded in a SAP portal, it was working fine on older version but in internet explorer the Dojo buttons, Tabs dose not work though they work in Chrome & Mozilla. We had tried adding website rules with HTTP response headers with code 200,206 and 302 also added custom header with parameter 'X-Frame-Options' ALLOW-FROM https://achme.com. Still there is no luck, any pointer would be highly appriciated.

Dojo Version is 1.9.7

Comment: Use the developer tools in IE11 to see the JS errors. that should provide additional hints

Comment: Use the Chrome and Firefox DevTools as well. They might be more forgiving and correctly render your page, but there may still be errors that are only visible using DevTools. The Page Source display in Firefox sometimes contains valuable information on the correctness of the HTML produced, search for tags in red.

Comment: the error is  because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.